# Node Express JS - need to restart the server app for each update of code

Tags: mysql, node.js, windows, express, server

Using the NodeJS command line tool, i need to restart the server via the command below set `DEBUG=myapp & npm start` (on Windows) when i update the source code. Is there any command to prevent that? e.g. auto restart the server while updating the source code? without end and restart the running  server each time.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) monitor your application and restart Node server after you have updated your code. You can also run specific commands :

https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: Yes, i know that, but the question is if i'm able to run the command below with Nodemon beacuse i already installed the nodemom from npm: set DEBUG=myapp & npm start